# Selenium driver.get(url) doesn't return control inspite of driver.set_page_load_timeout() being set

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code works for somewhere from 0 to 40 iterations but eventually **stalls on `browser.get(url)`** **even though the timeout parameter option is set**.

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(5)

for url in links:
    try:
       browser.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
       print("Webpage loading cut off")
```

The website queried is `onvista.de`, which updates data dynamically. That however shouldn't be handled by the `page_load_timeout` option.

I've tried working around it by setting up a thread before calling the `get` method and sending the `escape` key from that thread after 5 seconds; that however failed because a second thread can't access the webdriver at the same time that the first thread is using it.

I have really no idea what the issue could be at this point, so thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer, in case anyone has the same problem.

For some reason, I had Selenium 2.56 installed, updating via `pip -U selenium` to version 3 solved the issue.